# Multiple Activities Single Layout

Tags: android, layout, android-activity

I have many activities that do the same thing overall. Is it possible to have them use the same layout? I tried using the code below, but the layout would be shifted way to left to the point where buttons would be off the screen.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_pin);

TextView SecondEP = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EnterPin);
SecondEP.setText("Enter NEW Pin");
```

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be any problem with that, but if you are using the same layout to do the same thing in different `Activity` instances, you may want to look into setting up your doodad as a `Fragment` so it can be reused in both `Activity`s.

See the [Android Fragments Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for more information.